# There exist an analytic function/conformal map, f, that maps $\star$ bijectively onto $\star$

Tags: complex-analysis

Which of the following are true?

1. The function $f(z)=z^2+1$ is not conformal at $z=\pm i$
2. Given three distinct points $z_1,z_2,z_3\in \mathbb C$, there exist a Mobius transformation that maps $z_1$ to $0$, $z_2$ to $1$ and $z_3$ to $\infty$
3. Given a domain $D$ in the complex plane there exist an analytic function $f$ that maps the unit disk bijectively onto D
4. If $f$ is analytic in an open set $U$ and $z_0\in U$, then $f$ is conformal at $z_0$
5. If $f$ is an analytic function on the entire complex plane such that $\Re f(z)\leq0$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$,then $f$ must be a constant function
6. The image of a cicle under a Mobius transformation is a circle or line

---

1 is false as $f'(z)=2z=0$ at $z=0$, hence $f(z)$ is conformal at $z=\pm i$. 
2 is true because for distinct $z_1,z_2,z_3\in \mathbb C$, the Mobius transformation $f(z)=\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_3}\frac{z_2-z_3}{z_2-z_1}$ maps $z_1,z_2,z_3$ to $0,1,\infty$ respectively. 
4 is false because analytic bring conformality with non-vanishing derivative. 
6 is true.

I have no idea with $3$ and $5$. Specially how to deal with this format question, 
Is there exist an analytic function/conformal map, $f$, that maps $\star$ bijectively onto $\star?$

Comment: You don't need MathJax for ordinary text. You should also define $\star$.

Comment: I was wondering how to deal with it step by step, like for unit disk to half plane, semi disk to upper half plane etc. @SeanRoberson. I think one (any particular problem) step-by-step solution will give me enough idea. I didn't find any detail solution on M.SE.

Answer (score 1):

3. is false for $D= \mathbb C.$ Liouville !
4. Consider $g(z)=e^{f(z)}.$ Then $|g(z)|= e^{\Re f(z)} \le 1$ for all $z$.

Liouville says: $g$ is constant. Hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: Could you add some details? @Fred I can't connect why $D=\mathbb C$ make the statement false. For Liouville did you mean a bounded holomorphic function on the entire complex plane must be constant? And thanks for your response.

Comment: Suppose that $f: \mathbb D \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic and bijective. Then $f^{-1}: \mathbb C \to \mathbb D$ is an entire function and a bounded function. By Liouville: $f^{-1}$ is constant, a contradiction.

Comment: OK, I understood why $f^{-1}$ is constant but couldn't manage to understand which contradict what? Maybe I am asking so basic question, sorry for that. And did your lebeling $4$ is correct? I guess it was for $5$.

Comment: A constant function cannot be bijective !

Comment: Ah, How I forgot this!! Thanks, @Fred to clear my doubt.